# How can I provide my raspberry pi 2 with 3G/4G data?

Tags: pi-2, usb, internet, gsm, modem

I'm currently working on a project on my Rpi 2 model B that requires connection to internet through a cellular network via 3G/4G connection. I found some usb modem dongles and some modules, but they seem to have outdated/limited documentation. Is there any other hardware solutions that can work, specifically for Canada's cellular network? I'm willing to go for a slightly more complicated solution if it that's the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what country you're in so this might not be relevant, but I'd recommend a 4G router [like this](http://www.4g.co.uk/4g-mobile-broadband/). That has the benefit of creating a network you can join other devices to so they can interface rather than being exclusive to the PI. But does cost money for the data plan and router (though you can usually get deals) and probably isn't much more than a dongle.

Alternately if you have a 4G plan on your phone, turn it into a WiFi Hotspot and use that for an adhoc network, if you data plan allows it.

Comment: I live in Canada, the above dongle seems to be from UK but could probably work in Canada. How would you go about getting it to work with Rpi, is there any scripts you'd have to run?

Comment: It's just an example or the kind of thing you need I'm sure they do them in Canada. I wouldn't guarantee a UK one would work. Just search for a 4g hot-spot / router from a provider you know is reliable. As for working with the pi it's as simple as connecting to the adhoc wireless network the hotspot transmits (you'll have to have a USB wifi adapter for the pi 2 I don't think it's built in?)

Comment: Your solution requires the rpi connecting to another wirless network via it's wifi dongle (Rpi 2 needs one) which I will probably do at first, probably my cellphone. Later on I would need a solution where the Rpi itself will need 4G capabilities on it's own and that's where my issue lies.

Comment: Well. It depends what you want to do with it really. I only suggest a hotspot because of it's flexibility. You can upgrade your pi or use other devices with very little effort. If you want it entirely built in there are shield like this... https://www.cooking-hacks.com/documentation/tutorials/gprs-gsm-quadband-module-arduino-raspberry-pi-tutorial-sim-900/ however it depends what you want to do with it I wouldn't expect it to be easy to set up or usable as a traditional Internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

i already realized a similiar project. I just used a normal 3G USB Stick intended for a PC(Huawei -dont remember the type) The software I used was sakis3g. After installation and configuration according to the documentation the stick ran without problems. So I would recommend to have a look at sakis3g.

Regards Rolf

Comment: Is sakis3g still supported, their site doesn't seem to be up. I managed to get a tar file that has sakis3g software but not sure if it'll work.